# Prevent special characters like space in PHP

Tags: php

I have a field that users can enter whatever hey want, And I would allow them for decoration using special characters. but Now I really face with a big problem!

Special characters are like this: ♥♦☻NAME☻♦♥

And my really problem is 'alt+255' characters. it's like space and there are so many special characters like space. by the way My links are disabled and no one could select it.

There is a mandatory to enter more than only 1 character,

I want to know how to prevent this problem. my exact mean How can I let users enter special characters but still my links are clickable

Comment: Any code example for how the link is constructed?

Comment: How would a space break your links? What escaping do you do on link generation? Also: regex and `\pZ` probably.

Comment: You should use `urlencode` when creating a link from input that can contain special characters.

Comment: Possibly worth checking out a library like HTMLPurifier if you're allowing user input in HTML : http://htmlpurifier.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you are including the text in URLs then you really have two options. The most common approach is to strip out everything except for letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores (i.e. don't allow any special characters at all). You could use a simple regular expression replacement to do that.

Alternatively, you could allow all special characters, but escape them for use in links. You will find PHP's [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/urlencode) and [`urldecode()`](http://www.php.net/urldecode) useful for that.